# Saving changes in javascript file

Tags: javascript, input, savechanges

I have a html code that creates an input form on the browser and a javascript file that creates an array.The javascript program takes the input value and add it to the array and after display it on browser.

```
window.alert("Add some text")
var x;
var arr=["text1","text2"]
function myFunction() {
    x=document.getElementById('input').value;
    x=x.toLowerCase();
    var y=arr.indexOf(x);
    if (y!=-1) {
        window.alert("You have added this text before");
    } else {
        arr.push(x);
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=arr ;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I exit the file(the web page displayed on my browser) I lose the inputs.Let's say that I add "text3" and the program display text3,when I exit the browser I lose the input "text3".
What can I do to save the inputs and display them even if I exit the program and I enter again?
Can I make two javascript file one with the array(like a database) and one that takes the input and save it in the other javascript file,and if so how do I make it?

Answer (score 0):

As javascript is client side you will never be able to store permanent data as the script will be loaded (reset) after any refresh. Are you aware of the html5 localstorage concept? Saving data from js to the browsers storage space.

**Edit:**
Quick start on localstorage - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp